# incorrect number of dimensions even if the size of the array is the same

Tags: r, csv, matrix, dimension

I have been working on this program for many days, and decide to rewrite it today....
But this problem keeps bothering me.
I thought the `csm[1,]` and `Prank[1,]` has the same dimension.
Who can help me with this problem?

```
Prank<-read.csv("result.csv")


nrP<-nrow(Prank)
ncP<-ncol(Prank)

csm<-matrix(0,nrP*3,ncP)
ccsm<-matrix(0,nrP*3,ncP)

nrC<-nrow(csm)
ncC<-ncol(csm)

nrP
[1] 30
ncP
[1] 144
nrC
[1] 90
ncC
[1] 144
Prank[1,]
  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 P11 P12 P13 P14 P15 P16 P17 P18 P19 P20 P21 P22 P23 P24 P25 P26 P27 P28 P29 P30 P31 P32
1  4  2  3  1  4  2  3  1  4   2   3   1   3   1   4   2   4   2   3   1   4   1   3   2   4   1   3   2   4   2   3   1
  P33 P34 P35 P36 P37 P38 P39 P40 P41 P42 P43 P44 P45 P46 P47 P48 P49 P50 P51 P52 P53 P54 P55 P56 P57 P58 P59 P60 P61
1   4   1   3   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  P62 P63 P64 P65 P66 P67 P68 P69 P70 P71 P72 P73 P74 P75 P76 P77 P78 P79 P80 P81 P82 P83 P84 P85 P86 P87 P88 P89 P90
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  P91 P92 P93 P94 P95 P96 P97 P98 P99 P100 P101 P102 P103 P104 P105 P106 P107 P108 P109 P110 P111 P112 P113 P114 P115
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  P116 P117 P118 P119 P120 P121 P122 P123 P124 P125 P126 P127 P128 P129 P130 P131 P132 P133 P134 P135 P136 P137 P138
1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  P139 P140 P141 P142 P143 P144
1    0    0    0    0    0    0
csm[1,]
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [59] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[117] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
csm[1,]<-Prank[1,]
csm[1,]
Error in csm[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Which language is that? Can you add it in the tags so more people can check? Also, use correct formatting. The output you give is not easy to read...

Comment: Dear Matthieu, thank you so much,it's my first time to post

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Prank[1, ]` is a data.frame (i.e. a list) so when you try to assign it to the first row of `csm`, it has the unexpected side-effect of converting `csm` to a list. At that point, doing `csm[1, ]` does not make any sense (a list has a single dimension) hence the error.

A solution is to unlist `Prank[1, ]` before assigning:

```
csm[1,] <- unlist(Prank[1,])
```

Comment: You are very welcome, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

read.csv() returns a data.frame, and unless all of the columns of `Prank` are numeric, the assignment

```
csm[1,]<-Prank[1,]
```

will cause `csm` to be coerced to a list because `Prank[1,]` is not a numeric vector.  You will want to make sure that `Prank[1,]` is a numeric vector (i.e. `is.numeric(Prank[1,])`).

Revised suggestion: take a look at data.frame (`head(Prank)`) and it may be obvious that one or more columns are not numeric.  To inspect the classes of each field in prank, you can use

```
lapply(Prank,class)
```

or

```
sapply(Prank,class)
```

If all the fields in `Prank` are integer or numeric, you can coerce them all to numeric via

```
Prank[] <- lapply(Prank,as.numeric)
```

If not all the fields are numeric, you will want to coerce the problem fields to numeric, or
or remove the offending fields from `Prank` (e. g. `Prank$ProblemField <- NULL`) before the assignment.

Comment: `> Prank<-read.csv("result.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> 
> 
> nrP<-nrow(Prank)
> ncP<-ncol(Prank)
> 
> csm<-matrix(0,nrP*3,ncP)
> ccsm<-matrix(0,nrP*3,ncP)
> 
> nrC<-nrow(csm)
> ncC<-ncol(csm)
is.numeric(Prank[1,])
[1] FALSE`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to comment in a better way...But it seems that the elements in Prank[1,] is still not numeric

Comment: The coercion of `csm` to a list is correct. Everything else about the nature of the data (numeric or not) and the proposed solution is wrong I suppose.